# Can I access session variables stored by spring mvc from js front end

Tags: java, javascript, spring, session

I read another answer on stack overflow where use of session variables stored by spring mvc from jsp pages is explained.

What I wish to know is, can I access such session variables from JavaScript code in HTML front end for a web app that uses spring for it's backend? If yes then how do I access session variables from JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1):

No, not directly.

Consider that session variables exist in memory on the **server** and JavaScript executes in the browser on the **client**. Once this is clear, it should also be clear why you can't directly access session variables in client-side JavaScript.

If you need to read session-variables in your JavaScript code, there are ways around though.

1. You can render the value as a JavaScript variable on the page
2. You create a simple AJAX service (REST/JSON) so your page can make a request to the server using AJAX in the JavaScript and get the session variable value back

Comment: with ref to point 2 in your answer, cant such a service be easily abused by for eg hackers? Also can you point me to some sample code for both your points? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to iterate over session variables and print out a script which will set session attributes as array.

for eg in your jsp code:

add following line

```
<script>
var session= new Array();
<%
for (Enumeration e = session.getAttributeNames() ; e.hasMoreElements() ;) {
     Object obj= e.nextElement();
     %>session['<%=obj%>']='<%=(String)session.getAttribute(obj)%>';<%
   }
%>
</script>
```

This is assuming your session attributes are String.

Now you can access session attributes in browser javascript

for eg: `session['key1']`  will give String representation of Session attribute corresponding to key1 in server.

Comment: You realize you call e.nextElement() twice in each loop in your example, right?